# Position custom form in relation to WizardForm position

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have created a custom form to display an options page, which I am trying to position in the centre of wherever the `WizardForm` is at the time an Options button is clicked. I have tried the following code, but it is not positioning it as described.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  OptionsWindowForm: TForm;

{ Show the Options window }
procedure ShowOptionsWindow;
begin
  OptionsWindowForm := TForm.Create(nil);
  with OptionsWindowForm do
    begin
      Parent := WizardForm;
      BorderStyle := bsDialog;
      Position := poMainFormCenter;
      ClientWidth := ScaleX(400);
      ClientHeight := ScaleY(140);
      Caption := '{#AppName} Options';
      ShowModal;
    end;
end;
```

I also tried `poOwnerFormCenter` for the `Position` property and by setting `Left` and `Top` properties, which seem to be ignored.

Is there a way to position this as described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed does not seem to work as expected.

Though this seems to work:

```pascal
OptionsWindowForm := TForm.Create(WizardForm); { Make WizardForm the owner }
with OptionsWindowForm do
begin
  Position := poOwnerFormCenter; { Center on the owner }
  { ... }
  ShowModal;
end;
```

[image]